# MVC simple ajax GET bad request error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am learning the basics of MVC and I have problem whit the jQuery GET action, It always gives me back and 400 Error, a bad request error. This is my code:

In the view:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>SecurityNumber</h2>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecurityNumber, new { id="tbxSecurityNumber"})
<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get">
<input type="button" id="btnPost" value="Post">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#btnGet").click(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Html.ActionLink("tbxSecurityNumber","SecurityNumber")',
                data: { data1: jQuery('tbxSecurityNumber').val() },
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });

        jQuery("#btnPost").click(function () {

        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IndexGet(string data1)
{
    return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the generated HTML code.

Comment: `url: '@Html.ActionLink("tbxSecurityNumber","SecurityNumber")',` needs to be `url: '@Url.Action("IndexGet", "yourControllerName")',` (and delete the pointless `contentType` option (and why are you using `new { id="tbxSecurityNumber"}` instead of using the default `id` which is `SecurityNumber`?)

Comment: Look at the code that's generated in the browser, it will be something like:  `jQuery.ajax({ url: '<a href="... `.  You need to use `@Url.Action`.  Though this depends on the version of MVC you're using.

Comment: Infortunately the @URL change doent work

Comment: url: '<a href="/SecurityNumber/SecurityNumber">tbxSecurityNumber</a>', this is the URl i get in my generated HTML code, this sould be only  url: '<a href="/SecurityNumber">tbxSecurityNumber</a>', right?

Comment: Yes it does - look at the url your generating.

Comment: Did you read the previous comments - its `url: '/xxx/SecurityNumber',` (where `xxx` is your controller). You generate that with `@Url.Action()`, not `@Html.ActionLink()`

Comment: As above, `@Html.ActionLink` creates an html element, in this case an anchor, ie `<a href='..`.  For an ajax call you only want the href part without the html bits.  That's what `@Url.Action(...` does, you don't want anything with `<a href='anything` for an ajax call.

Comment: I managed to figure it out thanks @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 url: '@Html.ActionLink("link text", "tbxSecurityNumber", "SecurityNumber")',
```

or

```
url: '@Url.Action("tbxSecurityNumber", "SecurityNumber")',
```

there is a difference. Html.ActionLink generates an  tag whereas Url.Action returns only an url.

Comment: both are ActionLink ?

Answer (score 1):

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
            data: { data1: jQuery('tbxSecurityNumber').val() },
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (response) {
               alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
```

instead of @url.ActinLink give @url.Action.
one more thing while passing any value to controller use POST method rather than GET method.

Comment: If you change the jquery verb, don't forget to mention that you also need to change the back-end as the OP clearly has `[HttpGet] public JsonResult IndexGet(string data1)`.  So making on the change advocated here would not work as it's a GET only very.  Also you should only POST when you want to change something on the server!  In this case it's likely some kind of search/find and getting an index/table (hence `IndexGet`) so should most definitely be a GET not a POST.

Comment: it's ok.just i was trying to suggesting that if u want to post any data just use  verb as POST